# Area of a Rectangular in a Plane

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I have difficulties with solving a problem. I am coding it in python. May I have some help, please? So the condition says: A rectangular is set on 2 of its opposite angles (x1, x2) and (y1, y2). Find the **area** and the **perimeter** of the rectangular. The input is read from the console. The numbers `x1, x2, y1, y2` are given one by one on a line.

Inputs and Outputs:

[image]

An example:

[image]

my code:

```
x1 = float(raw_input("x1 = "))
y1 = float(raw_input("y1 = "))
x2 = float(raw_input("x2 = "))
y2 = float(raw_input("y2 = "))

if x1 > x2 and y1 < y2:
    a = x1 - x2
    b = y2 - y1
else:
    a = x2 - x1
    b = y1 - y1

area = a * b
perimeter = 2 * (a + b)

print area
print perimeter
```

Comment: You have a typo: `b = y1 - y1` (which is `0`). That should be `y2 - y1`?

Comment: So you want it for a rectangle or quadrilateral, because the user can enter anything, include coordinates for a irregular quadrilateral

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! If you haven't yet, please visit [ask] and [mcve] for guidelines on the sort of questions that work well here. Your post seems to be missing a specific question. Precisely what are you asking?

Comment: `a` and `b` just need to be the absolute difference of the two values; no `if` needed. `a = abs(x1 - x2)` and `b = abs(y1 - y2)`. (With `if`, you need to check `x` and `y` separately anyway.)

Comment: @ArmaGeddON Only two points define an infinite number of quadrilaterals, but they are sufficient to define a unique rectangle whose horizontal sides are parallel to the *x* axis.

Comment: It worked with the `abs()` method. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track!

Let me make a few suggestions:

---

#### Inputs

There is nothing wrong with this. (Unless you want to use Python3, where where `raw_input` is now just `input`)

```
x1 = float(raw_input("x1 = "))
y1 = float(raw_input("y1 = "))
x2 = float(raw_input("x2 = "))
y2 = float(raw_input("y2 = "))
```

#### Width and Height of the rectangle

If you use the builtin function `abs()`, you do not have to worry about the sign of `(x1 - x2)` and `(y1 - y2)`! Where `abs(x)` gives the absolute value of `x`.

```
width = abs(x1 - x2)
height = abs(y1 - y2)
```

#### Area and perimeter

Now that we have the height and width, we can use you code to calculate the area and perimeter:

```
area = height * width
perimeter = 2 * (height + width)
```

#### Bonus

Check if your rectangle is a square:

```
if height == width:
    print "It's a square!"
```

---

#### Putting everything together:

```
x1 = float(raw_input("x1 = "))
y1 = float(raw_input("y1 = "))
x2 = float(raw_input("x2 = "))
y2 = float(raw_input("y2 = "))

width = abs(x1 - x2)
height = abs(y1 - y2)

area = height * width
perimeter = 2 * (height + width)

print area
print perimeter

if height == width:
    print "It's a square!"
```

---

Let me know if you need me to explain anything!

Comment: `x1 = float(input("x1 = "))
y1 = float(input("y1 = "))
x2 = float(input("x2 = "))
y2 = float(input("y2 = "))

a = abs(x1 - x2)
b = abs(y1 - y2)

area = a * b
perimeter = 2 * (a + b)

print area
print perimeter`    I tried using only `input()` and it still works but I'd like to know if there is a difference in 'raw_input()' and 'input()' or the difference is only that in Python 2 is `raw_input` and in Python 3 is `input()`.

Comment: In Python 2 there **is** a difference! In Python 3 there only exist `input`, which is the same as the old `raw_input` and the old `input` does not exist anymore. See (the difference between raw_input and input)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x] for more detail.